# Sending files among other data with jQuery ajax not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying so hard to make this working and none of the solutions here or anywhere else seems to work for me. I don't know what I'm doing wrong and maybe I have a misunderstanding of how things work. 
I have some data, including an `input` of type `file`, all out of a `html form`. I want to send them all together through one `ajax` request and upload the file and also being able to handle the other data.

So I created an array with all the data(including the file data) with the name `the_data` and passed it to the `ajax` function.

And it doesn't work. The problem is not server side because the `ajax` request is never made. The problem is client side but I don't understand what might be the problem.

So here is my code:

```
function sentDataToSql(pos) {

    var data = new FormData();
    jQuery.each(jQuery('#photo-upload')[0].files, function(i, file) {
        data.append('file-'+i, file);
    });



    var numbers = $('#numbers').val();
    var my_address = $('#my-address').val();
    var signals=$('.signals').text();
    var date=new Date();
    var month=date.getMonth()+1;
    var day=date.getDay();
    var year=date.getFullYear();
    var finaldate=year+'-'+month+'-'+day;
    var dt = new Date();
    var time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes() + ":" + dt.getSeconds();
    var the_data={
        nums:numbers,
        address:my_address,
        type:'sometype',
        lat:pos['lat'],
        lng:pos['lng'],
        sigs:signals,
        time:time,
        date:finaldate,
        pic:data           //If I remove this everything will work(but of course the file won't be sent)

    };
    if(my_address!=''){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'../index.php',
            data:the_data,
        })

    }else{
            alert('Please .....! ')
    }


}
```

Non of the above data is in a `form` and all are outside a `form` as well as the input element with type `file` which looks like this:

```
<input type="file" name="photo" style="opacity:0;" id="photo-upload">
```

Here is my console log error :

```
TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement interface FormData.
```

**Edited code still not working after trying to put all data into a `FormData` object, and I get the same error as above:**

```
function sentDataToSql(pos) {

var numbers = $('#numbers').val();
var my_address = $('#my-address').val();
var signals=$('.signals').text();
var date=new Date();
var month=date.getMonth()+1;
var day=date.getDay();
var year=date.getFullYear();
var finaldate=year+'-'+month+'-'+day;
var dt = new Date();
var time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes() + ":" + dt.getSeconds();

var data = new FormData();
jQuery.each(jQuery('#photo-upload')[0].files, function(i, file) {
    data.append('file-'+i, file);
});
data.append('nums',numbers);
data.append('address',my_address);
data.append('type','homeless');
data.append('lat',pos['lat']);
data.append('lng',pos['lng']);
data.append('sigs',signals);
data.append('time',time);
data.append('date',date);

if(my_address!=''){
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'../index.php',
        data:data,
    })

}else{
        alert('Please locate your location first.')
}
```

}

Comment: Check the console for errors, I see 2 missing `;`

Comment: You need to set both `contentType` and `processData` to `false` in the `$.ajax()` call. More info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10811427/519413). You also need to append all the data to the `FormData` object and pass that. Currently you're passing the `FormData` as a child of an object which won't work.

Comment: @Xorifelse it's javascript and there is no need for ;  but here is my console log : TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement interface FormData.

Comment: @DevMan I am somewhat aware that single statements don't require a `;`, but heh, I'm consistent. Also, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21045034/4982088)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I did what you said but still not working. Please have a look at my code, I added to my question.

Comment: @Xorifelse You're right I also put it always and it's good that you reminded me but I was just saying that the error was not because of that.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I got it to work with I just forgot to set those 2 params to false. Thanks !